# Copy latest folder Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to copy the most lastet folder from insde a folder using gradle but I the script is sorting all the folders and copying the files inside the latest folder.

Below is the script.

```
task test(type: Copy) {
   from(new Source("D:\\test").listFiles().sort{ it.lastModified() }.last())
   into(new Source("D:\\folder\\output"))
}
```

What I got inside test directory is

```
test
└──folder1
|      test1.txt
└──folder2
|      test2.txt
```

If say folder2 in the test directory is the latest one tha I am getting the output as

```
test2.txt
```

But I am expecting the output as

```
folder2
 └─ test2.txt
```

and the content inside it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: please reformat the folder structure better, it's hard to understand.

Comment: Is this understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
task testCopy(type: Copy) {
    def latestDirName = file("test").listFiles().sort{ it.lastModified() }.last().name
    from file("test") , {
        include "$latestDirName/"
    }
    into(file("folder/output"))
}
```

***Explanation***

In your current task implementation, you have written:

`from(new Source("D:\\test").listFiles().sort{ it.lastModified() }.last())`

Which is equivalent to (assuming folder `folder1` is the most recent):

`from(new Source("D:\\test\\folder1"))`

Gradle will use `d:/test/folder1` as source folder for the copy: the content of this folder (*but not the folder itself*) will be copied to the destination directory.